# Ipad keyboard menu bottom of screen while typing

Tags: ipad, keyboard

Someone please tell me what this keyboard menu thing is that appears every time I start typing—-and how to TURN IT OFF. I’m using an IPad Air 4 with a Logitech folio touch keyboard. But it shows up without the keyboard too, so not sure if the hardware matters. See photo attached. It covers things up and I don’t every use it to switch between keyboard types. Don’t want it there ever. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could remember how to dismiss that  - [In the past, I was the guy asking in comments how to get this back once it’s dismissed...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295106/5472) I’ll try to get a bluetooth KB - but the Magic Keyboard and iPadOS 14 doesn’t look at all like your screen shot. (Thanks for adding that +1 for clarity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source: Let's Talk Tech](https://www.letstalk-tech.com/how-to-remove-predictive-text-bar-on-ipad-when-using-a-bluetooth-keyboard/).

> By default, the iPadOS keyboard has a predictive text & shortcut
> bar above the main QWERTY keyboard, offering things like formatting
> options and copy/paste buttons. When you hook up your hardware
> Bluetooth keyboard, however, this row of predictive text options and
> keyboard shortcuts sits at the bottom of your iPad display while you
> type.
>
> 1. On your iPad, open the Settings app.
> 2. Tap on `General > Keyboard`
> 3. Disable the following two options from that menu: "Predictive" & "Shortcuts"
>
> [image]
>
> That’s all. Once you disable those two options the on-screen predictive text bar will disappear and you can win back those extra pixels.

Comment: Thanks “Let’s Talk Tech”. That worked! Hopefully I’m not the only dope who couldn’t figure that out. I didn’t see anyone else with this problem anywhere  so maybe this will help out others.

Comment: @plainclothesninja I did this a few months ago but couldn't remember the exact steps.  This site gave a good overview as well as a picture, which is nice.  I'm glad it helped!

Comment: — Indeed. I’m new to this site and didn’t see your name there. Thanks again.